Efficient computation of number of partitions into powers of 2
Consider the function $a(n)$ defined as the number of partitions of $n$ into powers of $2$. The sequence is given at OEIS.
I am trying to calculate $a(n)$ modulo some fixed prime, for large $n$ and formulate algorithm that uses $O(\log n)$ basic arithmetic operations, or equivalently only $O(\log n)$ evaluations of the function $a(\cdot)$.
$a(n)$ has following recursive relations:
Recursive relation 1:
\begin{align}
a(2k+1)&=a(2k)\\
a(2k)&=a(2k-1)+a(k)
\end{align}
Recursive relation 2:
\begin{align}
a(n)&=
\begin{cases}
1, & n=0 \\
\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} a(i), & n>0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Both of these relations need $O(n)$ computations. We can modify the second recurrence and can obtain another recurrence relation for $a(16k+r)~\forall ~ r\in[0,15]$. For examples:
\begin{align}
a(16k) &= a(8k) + a(8k+2) + (4k-2) a(4k+2) + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (8k-2-8i) a(2k+2i)\\
a(16k+2) &= a(8k+2) + 4k a(4k+2) + \sum_{i=1}^{k} (8k+2-8i) a(2k+2i)
\end{align}
This relation also requires $O(n)$ computations. We can find similar recurrence relations of the form $a(2^mk+r)$, but still that will be $O(n)$ operations. Is it really possible to do better computationally?

Have you checked the links & references & code in the OEIS entry (and for https://oeis.org/A000123)?  If there is no fast algorithm listed there, then odds are that no fast algorithm is known.

I think what @Somos has described in the PROG section of the OEIS sequence, is similar to what I have done below, but I don't know PARI so can't be sure.

I'm guessing this is intended to solve Project Euler Problem 890. It's against the guidelines of Project Euler for solutions to the problems to be openly published, so I think it would be better if this question could somehow be removed. It might be too late now, though.

Several people have flagged this question for moderator intervention.  Please note that it is not against Math SE policy for people to Project Euler problems.  We enforce a contest problem policy, but this only applies to problems with an end date.  Project Euler does not fall into this category.  It is up to them to police their own policies.

Below is an $\mathcal{O}(\log^4 N)$ time algorithm to compute $a(N)$ modulo a fixed prime $p$.
You can also improve the algorithm to be in $\mathcal{O} \left( \left( \log N \cdot \log \log N \right)^2 \right)$ time using NTT to do the evaluations and interpolation (algorithms to do that described here). An extra condition required here is that $p$ is NTT-able for polynomials of degree $\approx 2\lfloor \log_2 N \rfloor + 2$, i.e., if $p-1$ is factorised into $2^rs$ where $s$ is odd, then $2^r \ge 4\lfloor \log_2 N  \rfloor + 6$. An example of a prime $\approx10^9$ which is NTT-able for very large polynimials is $p=998244353$, where $p-1=2^{23}\times119$.
Algorithm description
First I define a transformation operation on a given finite sequence $b = (b[0], b[1], \dots b[n])$ as $$f(b) = \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} b[i], \sum_{i=2}^{n} b[i], \sum_{i=4}^{n} b[i], \dots  \sum_{i = 2 \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor}^{n} b[i] \right)$$
Using the recurrence relation $2$ in the original post, its easy to see that
$$\begin{split}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} b[i] \times a(i) &= \sum_{i=0}^n \left(b[i] \times \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \right\rfloor} a(j) \right) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \right\rfloor} \left(b[i] \times  a(j)\right) \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor} \sum_{i=2j}^n  \left(b[i] \times  a(j) \right) \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor} \left(\left(\sum_{i=2j}^n b[i]\right) \times  a(j) \right) \\
\end{split}$$
or
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} b[i] \times a(i) = \sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor} f(b)[i] \times a(i)$$
This means to evaluate $a(N)$, we can evaluate the series of sequences $b_0, b_1, \dots b_{\lfloor \log_2 N \rfloor + 1}$, where $b_0 = (0, 0, \dots 0, 1)$ of size $N+1$, and $b_{i+1} = f(b_i)$ for each $i \in \{0, 1, \dots \lfloor \log_2 N \rfloor\}$. Then because $a(N) = \sum b_0[i]\cdot a(i) = \sum b_1[i]\cdot a(i) \dots = \sum b_{\lfloor \log_2 N \rfloor + 1}[i]\cdot a(i)$, and $b_{\lfloor \log_2 N \rfloor + 1}$ is just of size $1$, we get $A(N) = b_{\lfloor \log_2 N \rfloor + 1}[0]$.
Showing an example here, for $N = 19$, we get the following series of sequences:

$b_0 = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)$
$b_1 = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$
$b_2 = (10, 8, 6, 4, 2)$
$b_3 = (30, 12, 2)$
$b_4 = (44, 2)$
$b_5 = (46)$

So we get $a(19) = 46$.
Now the key to optimising in time, is to notice that for each $b_i$ for $i>0$, we can describe it as the evaluations of a $i-1$ degree polynomial, i.e., there exists a polynomial $p_i(x)$ of degree $i-1$, s.t., $b_i[j] = p_i(j)$ for all valid $j$. For the above example $b_2$ has the corresponding polynomial $p_2(x) = 10-2x$.
We can prove this via induction for all $N$: base step $b_1$ has polynomial $p_1(x) = 1$, and if $p_i(x)$ is expressed as $\sum c_j x^j$, then for any transformation $$\begin{split}
p_{i+1}(x) &= \sum b_i[j] - \sum_{y=0}^{2x-1} p_i(y) \\
&= C - \sum \left( c_j \sum_{y=0}^{2x-1} y^j \right) \\
\end{split}$$
And we know $\sum_{y=0}^{x} y^k$ has a degree of $k+1$.
So we don't actually have to evaluate the whole sequences $b_i$, but can work by only storing the $i$ coefficients of $p_i$. Then the transform will work by evaluating the last $2(i+1)$ values of $b_i$ (using $p_i$), using them to generate the last $i+1$ values of $b_{i+1}$, and then interpolating these values to form $p_{i+1}$.
Evaluation takes $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ time, and interpolation $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ time for a $n$-degree polynomial, which can be both improved to $\mathcal{O}(n \log^2 n)$ times using NTT. As our polynomials grow to a max size of $\log_2 N$ degree, and we do the transformations a maximum of $\log_2 N$ times, we get the time complexities described above.
Implementation
I implemented the above idea in C++, to verify my thinking. It seems to work for all the listed values in OEIS, but do let me know if it starts to crack above that.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class NumberOf2PowerPartitionsModuloP {
 private:
  int p;

  int pow(int x, int y) {
    int t = 1;
    while (y) {
      if (y & 1) t = 1LL * x * t % p;
      x = 1LL * x * x % p;
      y >>= 1;
    }
    return t;
  }

  int inverse(int x) { return pow(x, p - 2); }

  void checkPrime() {
    for (int x = 2; x * x <= p; x++) {
      if (p % x == 0) {
        cout << p << " is not prime!!";
        exit(1);
      }
    }
  }

 public:
  NumberOf2PowerPartitionsModuloP(int p) {
    this->p = p;
    checkPrime();
  }

  int compute(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1;

    int currentSize = (n >> 1), currentSelected = 0;
    vector<int> polynomial[2] = {vector<int>({1}), vector<int>()};
    vector<int> evaluations;

    while (currentSize > 0) {
      int nv = polynomial[currentSelected].size();

      for (int x = evaluations.size(); x <= 2 * nv + (currentSize & 1); x++) {
        int t = 1, sm = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nv; i++) {
          sm = (sm + 1LL * polynomial[currentSelected][i] * t) % p;
          t = 1LL * x * t % p;
        }
        evaluations.push_back(sm);
      }

      int y = 1;
      if (currentSize & 1) {
        evaluations[0] = (evaluations[0] + evaluations[1]) % p;
        y = 2;
      }
      for (int x = 1; x <= nv; x++) {
        evaluations[x] =
            (0LL + evaluations[x - 1] + evaluations[y] + evaluations[y + 1]) %
            p;
        y += 2;
      }
      evaluations.resize(nv + 1);

      currentSelected ^= 1;
      currentSize >>= 1;

      polynomial[currentSelected].clear();
      polynomial[currentSelected].resize(nv + 1, 0);
      for (int i = 0; i <= nv; i++) {
        vector<int> tmpPoly({1});
        for (int j = 0; j <= nv; j++) {
          if (i == j) continue;
          tmpPoly.push_back(0);
          for (int k = tmpPoly.size() - 1; k >= 1; k--) {
            tmpPoly[k] = (tmpPoly[k - 1] + p - (1LL * tmpPoly[k] * j % p)) % p;
          }
          tmpPoly[0] = (p - (1LL * tmpPoly[0] * j % p)) % p;
        }

        int coefficient = evaluations[i];
        for (int j = 0; j <= nv; j++) {
          if (i == j) continue;
          coefficient = 1LL * coefficient * inverse((i + p - j) % p) % p;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= nv; j++) {
          polynomial[currentSelected][j] =
              (polynomial[currentSelected][j] +
               1LL * tmpPoly[j] * coefficient % p) %
              p;
        }
      }
    }

    return evaluations[0];
  }
};

int main() {
  int n, p;
  cin >> n >> p;
  cout << NumberOf2PowerPartitionsModuloP(p).compute(n);
}

